# How do I get the files I uploaded in laravel?

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5

Seems really basic right, until you see that I use [Super Agent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) to upload my files:

```
  onDrop(files) {
    var req = request.post('//' + location.hostname + '/api/v1/blogs/image/upload').set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));

    files.forEach((file)=> {
        req.attach(file.name, file);
    });

    req.end((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

When I inspect the request object coming back:

[[image: Image[1]]

As you can see the file name could be anything so I can't just do: `$request->hasFile('photo')`

**Any ideas on how to handle this situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->allFiles()` will give you an array of all files, which you can `foreach` through.

Alternatively, [you can explicitly name the files in Super Agent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests) instead of using the file's name as the key.

```
req.attach('foobar', file);
```

If you're uploading multiple, you can likely do:

```
req.attach('foobar[]', file);
```